# Why does this work in console buy not in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker, strptime

I tried to solve this problem a thousand different ways looking at dozens of StackOverflow posts as well as outside tutorials dealing with DateTime, bootstrap datetimepicker, formatting, strptime, strftime, and on and on, without resolution. I have one basic question right now that may help me move forward.

Why does this work in my console:

```
 DateTime.strptime("09-29-2016 03:29 PM", "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")
   => Thu, 29 Sep 2016 15:29:00 +0000
```

But this fails in my app:

```
@image.start_at = DateTime.strptime(params[:start_at].to_s, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")
=>ArgumentError in ImagesController#create
invalid date
```

My start_at parameters come through as:

```
..."start_at"=>"09-29-2016 03:29 PM"},...
```

Also, this doesn't work in my app:

```
@image.start_at = DateTime.strptime(@image.start_at.to_s, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Comment: Hmm that is wierd.  It runs in my console fine as well.  Did you try adding `require 'time'`
`require 'date'` at the top of the file?

Comment: require 'date' has been on my image model for most of the time I've been trying to figure out this issue. I recently added it to image controller just to be certain I had it everywhere I might need it.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko start_at is part of my image_params. Essentially it is a column to store a date on my image model. I am trying to use an American style date and time which formatted appropriately for rails on the back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
@image.start_at = Date.strptime(params[:image][:start_at], "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Explanation:

1. you do not have to convert it to string - anything in params IS a String;
2. since the `start_at`'s type is a `Date`, you should pass a `Date` object to it, not a `DateTime` object.

If your `start_at` **IS** a datetime type (not date, as you've said in comments),

`@image.start_at = DateTime.strptime(params[:image][:start_at], "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")`

will work.

Comment: I am now receiving this error `TypeError in ImagesController#create
no implicit conversion of nil into String` My params passed through in the error still look like this` "start_at"=>"09-29-2016 04:28 PM"},` so I don't understand why it would consider it `nil`.

Comment: @Lenocam please add a `binding.pry` above the `@image.start_at = ...` code and debug. Meaning when the rails server terminal window will open the console, type in: `params[:start_at]` - ensure it's there. Than, run the actual code and see, if it works.

Comment: So I ran pry and typed params[:start_at] in my console, it responed `nil`, I don't understand why it would be nil. What do you mean "Run the actual code"?

Comment: @Lenocam so this is the answer, you have just checked if you really have it in params - you do not - thus error. Just a sanity check: can you run `params` and add output here?

Comment: `=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VkvT8GJ8HtSKoEQxrwiWHVgcwPuUIRX1GTjHkJmDqcz8MGqXoCu6rla2d29NjYwg2/PV5dmbFEXzuNx0txUZMA==",
 "image"=>
  {"file"=>"{\"id\":\"3703b5a83b678c6d0fb804866a2a87dc297f8f566f0361b3ae3127942fad\",\"filename\":\"c8f98ef4b2acc1754bab905ee8d61afe.jpg\",\"content_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"size\":33018}",
   "category_ids"=>["", "25"],
   "start_at"=>"09-29-2016 04:45 PM"},
 "commit"=>"Create Image",
 "controller"=>"images",
 "action"=>"create",
 "user_id"=>"25"}
`

Comment: @Lenocam the problem is easy: learn how to access nested hash elements ;) basically it should be `params[:image][:start_at]`

Comment: Why does it show start_at as a string with the date in it if it is coming back `nil`

Comment: thanks for your help. this carried me further and I appreciate it, I changed Date back to DateTime and time pushed through as well, good night

Comment: @Lenocam try `@image.start_at = DateTime.strptime(params[:image][:start_at], "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")` - may be it will work, which mean you have the correct datatype in database. Let me know if it works

Comment: @Lenocam please accept the answer (checkmark on the left near answer) since it solved the initial problem. Consider asking a new question should you have any things to solve next.